# SQL for specific count of table entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create an `SQL` query to return some specific information.

```
214 6255    en-us   4  
62  6259    en-us   4  
64  6260    en-us   4  
63  6262    en-us   4  
69  6264    en-us   4  
70  6255    en-us   4
```

This would be an example layout in the table. The first column would be a for example spID, the second is userID.

What I need to find is the count of the rows that the UserID has. So in the above example the UserID 6255 has 2. I would like the results to be like this:

```
6255   2  
6259   1  
6262   1  
6264   1
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wait? all your doing is counting amount of times the user turns up in your table?

if so cant you just...

```
Select userid, COUNT(userid) as UserTotal
From yourtable
group by userid
```

or do you need more?

Comment: You are right, I figured this moments after posting. Thanks Steven

Comment: hehe nps, sometimes we all over look the simple stuff, christ i do it too much lol

Comment: easy solution? to the coffee machine!

Answer (score 0):

```
select userID,  count(*) as TotalEntries
from table_name
group by userID
```

Hope this solves your query.